# Multi-type container C++. Casting to derived template class

Tags: c++, templates, casting, polymorphism, derived-class

I am trying to implement a multi-type container in C++ without using `std::any`, `std::variant`, `boost::any`, etc. The `add()` function adds new objects (`int`, `string`, or other `Structure`s) by wrapping them in the template element class and storing as `Structure` pointers:

```
using StructPtr = std::shared_ptr<Structure>;

class Structure{
    public:
        Structure() = default;
        Structure(const Structure& oldStruct);
    
        Structure operator = (Structure otherStruct);
        bool operator == (const Structure& otherStruct);
    
        template<class T>
        void add(T obj){
            elements.emplace_back(std::make_shared<Element<T>>(obj));
        }
    
        void print(std::ostream& out);
        
        std::vector<StructPtr> elements;
};
    
template<class T>
class Element : public Structure{
    public:
        Element() = default;
        Element(T _element) : element(_element) { }
        Element( Element& oldElement){
            element = oldElement.element;
        }
    
        T element;    
};
```

I have a print function that takes in an element and prints it:

```
template<class T>
void printElement(std::ostream& out, const Element<T>& element){
    printElement(out, element.element); //this functionality has been provided already.
}
```

I want to go through each element in the vector and pass it to this print function. However, since they are stores as `StructPtr`s, I do not know how to cast them into this templated `Element` class (I cannot use `dynamic_cast`).

This is what I tried:

```
template<class T>
void printElement(std::ostream& out, const std::vector<StructPtr>& elements){
    for(auto element : elements){
        auto elementDerived = static_cast<Element<T>>(*element);
        printElement(out, elementDerived);
    }
}

void printElement(std::ostream& out, const Structure& s){
    printElement(out, s.elements); 
}
```

But this gives an error:

```
no instance of overloaded function "printElement" matches the argument listC/C++(304)
task01.cpp(64, 5): argument types are: (std::__1::ostream, const std::__1::vector<StructPtr, std::__1::allocator<StructPtr>>)
```

So, my main question is, how do I call:

```
template<class T>
void printElement(std::ostream& out, const Element<T>& element)
```

on each element of the vector?

Comment: Not clear what you're asking for. Once you've erased type, you can't reconstruct it to compile-time type (no template virtuals or anything like that in C++), hence we have variants / virtual overrides to solve it.

Comment: add a method `void printElement(std::ostream& out) const;` and override it from `Element`. By the way, is it deliberate that `Element` inherits the `elements` member from `Structure`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't perform a `static_cast` inside of `printElement()` since you don't know what to cast to (`dynamic_cast` would have helped you with that), so the only solution is to make `Structure::print()` be `virtual` and have `Element` override it, eg:

```cpp
class Structure{
    public:
        ...        
        virtual void print(std::ostream& out) const {
            printElement(out, elements);
        }
        ...
};
    
template<class T>
class Element : public Structure{
    public:
        ...    
        void print(std::ostream& out) const override {
            printElement(out, element);
        }
        ...
};

void printElement(std::ostream& out, const std::vector<StructPtr>& elements){
    for(auto element : elements){
        element->print(out);
    }
}
```

Comment: I need to allow instantiation of Structure class so I can't make it a pure virtual function. If I make it just virtual with an empty implementation, will it call the print from the derived class?

Comment: @callumarul "*I need to allow instantiation of Structure class so I can't make it a pure virtual function*" - I have updated my example. "*will it call the print from the derived class?*" - if it is called on a pointer to a derived instance, then yes.